# Inno Setup Semaphore non GUI Blocking

Tags: inno-setup, semaphore

I have an Inno Setup script which calls a DLL. 
The DLL starts a thread which in the end calls a function pointer in the Inno Setup.
Since i don't want to change the logic of my Inno Script to much i would like to use a semaphore or something like that.

The important part in here is that the gui shouldn't be blocked.

here a little snippet of my code

```
procedure InstallData();
var
    arrComponents           : TStringList;
    i, index, p             : Integer;
    countComp               : Integer;
begin
    countComp := ICountComponents();
    pbState.Max:= countComp;
    arrComponents := IGetComponentsToInstall(); 
    pbState.Max := countComp;

    for i := 0 to countComp-1 do
    begin
        // lock semaphore

        pbState.Position := i;
        p := Pos(' ', arrComponents[i]);
        if p > 0 then 
        begin
          //Unzip component
          //Call the DLL
        end
        else 
        begin
           //unzip something else
           //Call the DLL
        end 
    end
end;

procedure ProgressCallback(progress:Integer);
begin
    pbStateZip.Position:= progress; 
    //if progress = 100
    // unlock semaphore
    // 
end;
```

Are there semaphores or is there an equivalent to this which does not block my GUI ?

Comment: So you want to wait for a synchronization object in Inno Setup without blocking the UI ? If so, then it makes little sense to me since you are having that callback. Create a thread in DLL, do the work, call the callback. That's the scenario I could imagine.

Comment: The callback is there for returning the progress so when this reaches a 100% then the semaphore should be released. I agree that changing the algorithm would be also okay but i don't want to change the for loop in which the unzip happens ;)

Comment: The message pump of the main UI thread must not be blocked by any synchronous function call to keep the UI *alive*. And for that semaphore signal you would need to wait somehow. There are at least 3 possible options I can think of, 1. add some sort of on-finished event calback delegate, 2. find an asynchronous wait mechanism, 3. create a waiting thread in the setup, or a window with the *dummy* message loop and switch to Windows messaging.

Comment: Of course these 3 options are there but i hoped for a semaphore :/ . Okay so i will try to implement one of those three. Thanks so far :)

Comment: I haven't said you couldn't use semaphore :) Options 2 and 3 are just proposals for making asynchronous waiting (e.g. on semaphore). Anyway, you must not access UI controls from a worker thread, so be very careful what you do in the `ProgressCallback` function if you are invoking that callback from a worker thread.